# google checkout get custom variable at continue url

Tags: php, google-checkout

I am working with google checkout and currently working at sandbox environment. I have used Paypal and i thought google checkout should work like the same. but i wonder that google checkout is not posting back the HTML form field on return URL and im not able to find any proper solution for this problem yet. Here is my code.

here im using a custom field shopping-cart.merchant-private-data to get the data but i dont know how to collect that data on continue URL.

I just need to pass some ID in a custom field so that on return URL I can get it back and then change my database on the basis of this ID. There is one thing which is important that Upon return google checkout is destroying sessions also and there is no value stored in sessions. This made a big problem for me. So please tell me how i can get that custom ID back from google checkout.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of separate issues here:

***First***, there is no automatic re-direct for the buyer after the Google Checkout transaction finishes.

The `continue-shopping-url` paramenter allows you to provide a link that the user ***has*** to click in order to get back to your site after completing the order. Because this is just a link, there is no data post, such as the transaction private data you are looking for.

More info about the continue-shopping-url paramenter:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Parameter_Reference.html#tag_continue-shopping-url

***Second***, you can use the `<merchant-private-data>` tag to pass any custom data about your order. To get it back you have to provide a callback URL in order to receive notifications from Google Checkout. When you get back the notification, read the custom info from the merchant-private-data tag .

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333835/google-checkout-xml-api-associate-callback-serial-number-with-original-order) for a solution to a similar issue.