# Not receiving response when using Google Checkout

Tags: php, google-checkout

I'm new to Google Checkout, I went throw the examples but still have some problems. I'm able to create the order throw HTML and XML, but I need to be able to know in my system that the order was paid. I try the notification callback an polling, but I'm not sure how can I link the Google order with my order in the system. I check the response XML but didn't found any way how to post my ID and get it back. There is merchant-private-data, but I'm not getting the value back. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It may help to include some of your code, in case you're putting your merchant private data in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get back the notification, you should be able to read the merchant-private-data.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3333835/602119) which touches on a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

When submitting orders using google checkout, keep an order in your system with unique order ID, this id is sent to google as merchant private data. Once google process the orders, it will notify the reposnse throught API call back URL. We can read the data in response handler file and modify the order accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of response from Google with various order status. The merchant data will be received only initial responses. There is unique google order number in response, which also used to track order for further reference.