# How can I correlate the response from Google Checkout to the correct order in the database?

Tags: java, google-checkout

When I get the notifications from google at the callback URL I am unable to correlate the messages to the correct order in the database. Can I pass some identifier that would be sent back to me as a part of the callback notification? How is this done in general?

I am using the latest google-checkout-java SDK.

Comment: I am trying to find the answer to this same question. Is there an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use your merchant-private-data-section for this

```
<checkout-shopping-cart xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2">
  <shopping-cart>
    <merchant-private-data>
      <your-ref>019b1723a2754981ed5bc24e6ac9f501</your-ref>
    </merchant-private-data>
    [...]
  </shopping-cart>
</checkout-shopping-cart>
```

When you get the notification, you can read this data.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3333835/602119) and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333835/google-checkout-xml-api-associate-callback-serial-number-with-original-order/4979332#4979332). I'd only note additionally that you don't have to use `merchant-note` (or `your-ref`), but can define any tags of your own as merchant-private-data is [defined](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/apiv2.xsd) as a sequence of `xs:any`.
Hope that helps...