# google checkout,How to find payment completed in API callback

Tags: php, api, google-checkout

Now i am working with Google checkout payment.I want to find the payment completion using API callback url,And i need to send an email to the payer,When he complete the payment.Can  anyone help me with some example codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Notification API to get transaction information back from Google Checkout.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html

When you get back the notification, you can read your custom ID from the merchant-private-data field.

Source [get value return in google checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977151/get-value-return-in-google-checkout)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For code examples on using the Google Checkout APIs please have a look at the "Client Libraries & Sample Code" section in the Checkout developer documentation:

https://developers.google.com/checkout/samplecode