# Googlecheckout,Payment completion XML

Tags: php, xml, google-checkout

I got an xml after completing Google checkout payment.I need to update my database after completing the payment, The xml is like the following.In which stage like "merchant-calculation-callback" the payment completing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<merchant-calculation-callback 
     xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2"
     serial-number="c2406a1f-6971-4c0f-899e-415ef621dfb46">
```

Comment: We can see the XML content by sending as email

Answer (score 0):

`<merchant-calculation-callback />` is used in [Merchant Calculations API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Merchant_Calculations_API) - its a callback in the **Checkout** process (aka [**Part 1** in the Google Checkout API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/))- Google sends the callback to your systems asking for calculations - e.g. shipping, tax, promotions, hence the name *merchant-calculation-callback*.

**Part 1**/Checkout - is the part where **you send** data to Google for Checkout. Therefore it is **not** going to give you information related to *"after completing payment"*

---

**Part 2/Processing Checkout Orders** covers the APIs you can use to **obtain** order data *"after completing payment"* - primarily the [Notification API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API). These APIs are what you must implement in order to get data for integration with your own order-processing systems (e.g. order status, payment status, saving order data, updating inventory, etc.).

- Order processing [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Custom_Processing_How_To)

---

You seem to be asking the same/related questions:

- [get value return in google checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5977151/304683)
- [google checkout,How to find payment completed in API callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10595830/304683)