# How to handle call back url in the google checkout for multiple websites?

Tags: url, asp-classic, callback, google-checkout, merchant-account

I have been working on google checkout integration in classic ASP, my client have various eCommerce websites and want to use single merchant account (Google Checkout) for all websites.
I have set up the callback url in merchant account, but I  need to identify from which website's order has been placed, to save information in the database.

Can I specify a callback url from the code itself, for each different website using the single merchant account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the merchant-private-data field to pass any custom data about your order (including the website info).

When you get back the notification, read the custom info from the merchant-private-data field and identify from which website it originated.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333835/google-checkout-xml-api-associate-callback-serial-number-with-original-order) for a solution to a similar issue.