# Magento Multistore - Single Google Checkout

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I have two stores with different url
store1.com and store2.com 
I also confirm the Callback URLs for both the store is correct and working

```
https://store1.com/googlecheckout/api/ and https://store2.com/googlecheckout/api/
```

In my google Checkout a/c, there is only one place for Integration Settings where I can provide API Callback url and API Version and Callback Content Type?

Is it possible to have a multi store work with single Google checkout a/c?
If yes where and what do i need to provide values for API Callback in my Google Checkout Integration Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your merchant profile setting is **static**

   - this means both your stores *share the same name/support contact/type of merchant, etc.*
   - so your first decision is whether or not this works for both stores in the eyes of your customers (or potentially cause confusion - e.g. `ACME Enterprises` may work, but `ACME Computers` may not work if one store sells computers, while the other sells bags).
2. If the static profile works for both stores, and *you are implementing the API internally/your own developer(s)*, you can [use merchant-private-data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151411/304683) with a single callback API URL and determine the source of the order that way. If you are relying on 3rd parties for the API implementation, you may have to ask that 3rd party if this is something they support.
3. If for any reason, you definitely need 2 separate/distinct API Callback URLs, then your only choice is to create a separate account for each store. You can only have one Callback API URL in your account and it's not dynamic (it must be set in your account). This would also be true if the static merchant profile will not work for both stores.